# Get certain strings only (PHP)

Tags: php

Text:

```
TestString
HT-Child1 CLASS-Class1
AnotherString
HT-Child2 CLASS-Class2
HT-Child3 CLASS-Class3
HT-Child4 CLASS-Class4
CLASSOFWEEK-Class
```

What I have so far: (Inside `$display->getExtraHTML()` is the text). Could someone guide me towards what I need to do to adapt my code to get the results I want.

```
<?php 
    $additionalHTML = explode("\n", $display->getExtraHTML());
    $html = "";
    $html .= "<ul>";
        foreach($additionalHTML as $key => $item){
            $html .= "<li>$item</li>";
        }
    $html .= "</ul>";
    echo $html;
?>
```

I know I can use something like this to get string between, but how do I use it to get all the values i need?

```
$string = strstr($display->getExtraHTML(), "HT-"); // gets all text from HT
$string = strstr($string, "CLASS-", true); // gets all text before CLASS
```

Can I use both `explode` and `strstr` to get to where I want?

Expect HTML markup:

Expected Result: (Get the values from `HT-` and `CLASS-`)

```
<ul>
   <li>Child1 Class1</li>
   <li>Child2 Class2</li>
   <li>Child3 Class3</li>
   <li>Child4 Class4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the downvote for?

Comment: `/^HT\-(\w+)\s+CLASS\-(.+)$/` -  https://regex101.com/r/vu7Fhv/1

Comment: Have you tried using `explode` or `strstr`? Is there anything not working using these functions?

Comment: @ChrisBeckett, post the expected html markup

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - Expected html markup added

Comment: @NicoHaase - Please read my question

Comment: @ChrisBeckett - your question was "Can I use both explode and strstr to get to where I want?" and I was asking whether you have just tried to. There are only little less complex functions in PHP than explode. But the regular expression splash58 posted also looks good, so probably you want to go that way

Comment: I edited it. Try running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete solution with `preg_match_all` function:

```
$txt = '
TestString
HT-Child1 CLASS-Class1
AnotherString
HT-Child2 CLASS-Class2
HT-Child3 CLASS-Class3
HT-Child4 CLASS-Class4
CLASSOFWEEK-Class';

preg_match_all('/^HT-(\S+)\s+CLASS-(\S+)/m', $txt, $m);
$html = "<ul>";
if (isset($m[1]) && isset($m[2])){
    foreach(array_map(null, $m[1], $m[2]) as $pair){
        $html .= "<li>". implode(' ', $pair) ."</li>";
    }
}

$html .= "</ul>";
echo $html;
```

The output (push *Run code snippet*):

```html
<ul><li>Child1 Class1</li><li>Child2 Class2</li><li>Child3 Class3</li><li>Child4 Class4</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution

```
 <?php
$str = "TestString
HT-Child1 CLASS-Class1
AnotherString
HT-Child2 CLASS-Class2
HT-Child3 CLASS-Class3
HT-Child4 CLASS-Class4
CLASSOFWEEK-Class";



    $additionalHTML = explode("\n", $str);
    $html = "";
    $html .= "<ul>";
        foreach($additionalHTML as $key => $item){
          if(substr($item,0,3) == "HT-") {
            $i = explode(" ",$item);
            $a = substr($i[0],3);
            $b = substr($i[1],6);
            $html .= "<li>$a"." ". "$b</li>";
          }
        }
    $html .= "</ul>";
    echo $html;
```

Result

```
Child1 Class1
Child2 Class2
Child3 Class3
Child4 Class4
```

Comment: This only gets the Child1, Child2, Child3. Not the Class1, Class2, Class3 aswell.

Comment: Did you try running this solution?

Comment: Yes and it only returns Child1, Child2, Child3

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: I printed out the `$i` and it returned the following - `Array ( [0] => HT-Child1 [1] => [2] => CLASS-Class1 ) Array ( [0] => HT-Child2 [1] => [2] => CLASS-Class2 ) Array ( [0] => HT-Child3 [1] => [2] => CLASS-Class3 )` and then the end result is only displaying Child1, Child2, Child3

Comment: But that's the output you want to right? I provided you the solution and you can run the snippet. Trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use regex, to find the matching lines and extract required data:

```
if(preg_match("/HT-([A-Za-z0-9]+) CLASS-([A-Za-z0-9]+)/", $item, $output))
{
    $html .= "<li>".implode(" ",array_slice($output,1))."</li>";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. I've tested this and nothing happens.